# Custom TextInputLayout does not apply correct styling with default constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-custom-view, default-constructor

I've created two examples of code in which one is applying the correct styling to the `TextInputLayout` and the other is not. I would like to understand why this is happening. In my eyes they should be exactly the same. The only difference is whether I define the constructor as primary or secondary constructor. In both cases I call the 3 argument constructor of the super.

This applies the correct styling to the `TextInputLayout`:

```
class CustomTextInputLayout : TextInputLayout {

// Primary constructor does not apply correct styling i.c.m. ContextThemeWrapper
@JvmOverloads
constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int = com.google.android.material.R.attr.editTextStyle,
    @StyleRes defStyleRes: Int = com.google.android.material.R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox
) : super(ContextThemeWrapper(context, defStyleRes), attrs, defStyleAttr)

private val layout: TextInputLayout = this
private val edit: TextInputEditText = TextInputEditText(context)

init {
    addEditBox(edit)
    layout.hint = "This is the hint"
}

private fun addEditBox(editText: TextInputEditText) {
    val layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    editText.layoutParams = layoutParams
    addView(editText)
}
```

This **DOES NOT** apply the correct styling to the `TextInputLayout`:

```
class CustomTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int = com.google.android.material.R.attr.editTextStyle,
    @StyleRes defStyleRes: Int = com.google.android.material.R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox
) : TextInputLayout(ContextThemeWrapper(context, defStyleRes), attrs, defStyleAttr) {

private val layout: TextInputLayout = this
private val edit: TextInputEditText = TextInputEditText(context)

init {
    addEditBox(edit)
    layout.hint = "This is the hint"
}

private fun addEditBox(editText: TextInputEditText) {
    val layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    editText.layoutParams = layoutParams
    addView(editText)
}
```

I hope that someone can explain to me why I need to define it as secondary constructor. Or provide a solution where the styling is applied with a primary constructor.